# Easy way to convert Spotify Simple Player from a xib to a storyboard?

Tags: xcode, spotify

Is there an easy way to convert the Spotify Simple Player app from using a XIB file to using a storyboard instead? I want to include a variation of the Simple Player in my current xcode project, but I am using a storyboard since I am fairly new to IOS programming. Is there an easy way (or any way) to make the Simple Player run with a storyboard? Any things in particular I should and should not change?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, there's so little code in SimplePlayer that it'd be easier to build it from scratch and copy the code in. Once you've built the UI, hook the play button up to an outlet and copy+paste the code in from the play button in Simple Player.

Comment: I'm trying to build my own from scratch, I'm just so lost on how to get libspotify into my app properly... as I've never integrated 3rd party libraries into a project before (it took me long enough just to get the Simple Player running right). Unfortunately, what I could really use is step by step instructions on how to create a new empty app with the library. Sadly, I'm just wasting (a lot of) time experimenting on getting this to work right. What will probably take me 100 hours to get correct is something you probably do in your sleep.

Comment: for reference: [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-music-library-access/) is how I learned how to get the IPOD media player integrated in my app (like I've said I'm new to this). Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be anything like this for Spotify... yet.. I do really appreciate your help. I know it must be frustrating to deal with people as 'clueless' as me

Comment: There's instructions in the README, under the "Building" headers. Otherwise, check out the "Empty CocoaLibSpotify Project" sample project which is an empty project with CocoaLibSpotify included, ready for your app.

Comment: for some reason I couldn't get the empty project to run yesterday, but today I can, and it is working. So once again, thanks for your time. Hopefully I'm good from here out

Comment: does the code used to login to spotify and the play button need to be in the appdelegate or can it be placed in the viewcontroller? i can't seem to get the music to start playing when placing it in the view controller. The log in to Spotify is working however. And the play button is hooked up and working (added some logs to verify that the play button is working and that the trackURI length is >0) .... for reference, i am using the play button code from the Simple Player in the empty app... edit: for reference:    [screenshot](http://imgur.com/elfeN)

Comment: It doesn't matter where the code is. Remember you need to set up an `SPPlaybackManager` to hear audio.

Comment: I'm almost there. I can feel it. But when I created the SPPlaybackManager (based on the one in the Simple app), I keep getting errorred out. [see here for details](http://i.imgur.com/Nvs3k.png) ... using self.playbackManager is also giving me an error ...  this is all in the ViewDidLoad method... do I have this in the wrong order? did I set up SPPlaybackManager wrong?

Comment: GOT IT! I was missing the -(void)observeValueForKeyPath method underneath the viewDidLoad!!
thanks for the help!